# Intersection of a compact subset and a closed subset of a metric space is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I got this question in a test assignment: Let $K$ and $C$ be subsets of a metric space $X$. Show that if $K$ is compact and $C$ is closed, then $K \cap C$ is compact.

The tutor opted for the method starting with an open cover of $K \cap C$. I used the fact that compact subsets of metric spaces are closed, to then show that $K \cap C$ is closed and since $K \cap C$ is a closed subset of compact set $K$,  $K \cap C$ is also compact.

However the tutor barely gave me any marks and left a note: "how do you justify the fact that K is a metric space or subspace, for you to be able to invoke the result that  K n C, a closed subset of a compact metric space or a compact metric subspace is compact? So far, K is just a compact subset of X with no mention of any induced metric."

I don't really understand the comment or the need to define a metric on $K$.

Comment: I could be wrong, but this is how I see it. I think the tutor was okay with your assertion that $K\cap C$ is closed. Maybe they wanted you to explicitly prove that since $K$ is compact, $K\cap C\subset K$ is compact. Prove this using open covers, rather than citing a result.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is almost complete. You showed that since $K$ is a compact subset of $X$(where $X$ is your parent space) it is closed. Therefore $K \cap C$ is a closed subset of $X$. But this does not (depending on what facts you're allowed to use) mean $K \cap C$ is a compact subset of $X$. Instead, you used the fact that $K \cap C$ is a closed subset of $K$(not $X$) to show that $K\cap C$ is a compact subset of $K$. You were required to show that $K \cap C$ is a compact subset of $X$. You're almost done, since compactness is a topological property, $K \cap C$ is automatically a subset of $X$.

So basically, you're required to stipulate the additional(important) fact that if $A \subset B \subset X$, where $X$ is a metric space, then $A$ is compact as a subset of $B$ if and only if $A$ is compact as a subset of $X$.